# Overloading '+' to add two matrices

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

This is a class with object 'matrix' that holds a dynamic 2D array.  I want to make it so I can add two matrices onto another one.  E.g:  a = b + c; and the sum of corresponding elements in b and c (such as b[1][1] + c[1][1]) will go onto a[1][1]

However I'm getting "error: expected initializer before '.' token.  Not sure what to do here

```
//.h file
Square_Matrix& operator+(const Square_Matrix& Par);

//.cpp file
Square_Matrix& Square_Matrix::operator +(const Square_Matrix& Par){
    Square_Matrix result;
    Square_Matrix result.Set_Size(Par.Get_Size);
    for (int i = 0; i < Par.Get_Size; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < Par.Get_Size; i++){
            result.matrix[i][j] = Par.matrix[i][j] + matrix[i][j];
        }   //assume matrix size will always be the same
    }

 return *this;  //is this correct as well?
}
```

Comment: Sorry, disregard that I fixed it

Comment: you don't do anything with `result`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
Square_Matrix result.Set_Size(Par.Get_Size);
```

with

```
result.Set_Size(Par.Get_Size);
```

since you already declared `result` on the previous line. (You cannot declare a variable and call a method on it in the same statement.)

(Also, assuming `Square_Matrix::Get_Size` is a method, you need to call it with parentheses, *i.e.*, `Par.Get_Size()`)

Comment: Looks like they're also missing some `()`s.

Comment: @JosephMansfield indeed

Comment: Ahh thanks, so besides that does it look like my code should work fine?

Comment: @Foxic see the edit I made and Joseph Mansfield's comment above

Comment: Also the comment by BWG on the question

Comment: Not sure if this will be solvable but, after changing both things you mentioned ^ my program now closes with no error. Just "Square_Matrix has stopped working"

Comment: Perhaps you should try using the debugger

Answer (score 1):

You are also incrementing i again inside the nested loop.